# QPushButtons in a QGroupBox won't resize when the window is resized,

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a main window with some QGroupBox's in and within those boxes I have some QPushButtons and QLabels. I am trying to set it up so when the window is resized the pushbuttons and labels resize to fill the QGroupBox but all that seems to happen is the group boxes increase in size but the labels and buttons within those boxes stay the same size, an image link below shows the current behaviour when the window is expanded.

[image]

As you can see the to push buttons are staying the same size when the group box they are in is expanding.

Can anyone tell me the correct Qt Designer settings (or if there is a better way of laying this out) to achieve the functionality that I require?

The py file was created from the ui file output by Qt Designer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>272</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>80</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="horizontalLayoutWidget">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>601</width>
       <height>51</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>121</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>10</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>601</width>
       <height>91</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>TextLabel</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The file used to open the window and attach the group box's to the lytMain

```
**import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from resize_error import *

class MenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.lytMain = QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.lytMain)
        self.lytMain.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.lytMain.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mnuMain = MenuMain()
    mnuMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())**
```

Comment: The behaviour you describe should immediately make it clear to you that some of the relevant container widgets don't have layouts. In Qt Designer, the Object Inspector will display an icon with a red stop-symbol next to any such widgets. So give them all an appropriate layout and then go to *Form/Preview...* and check that the ui behaves as you expect. If you do things properly, there should be no need to manually add layouts within your code.

Comment: @ProgramMasher also, for future reference, try to provide examples that are *both* [minimal *and* reproducible](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): your code (which is more than 300 lines) contains a *lot* of widgets, while you could have produced an example showing the same issue with a fraction of items, and your main script also contains modules we don't know anything about, forcing us to make modifications you could (should) have done in the first place. Finally, if the problem is related to a Designer UI, consider providing *that* instead of the pyuic file.

Comment: Thanks this helped and I now have it performing how I wanted. It wasn't immediately obvious why they did not have appropriate layouts as I thought I had added the layouts to the group boxes but as you say they all had red stop boxes next to them. I will answer the question by explaining what I had done wrong and how I fixed it.

Comment: @musicamante although the question was answered I have updated it as per your requests, mainly for future reference and partly to see if I have updated it to be a better question (i.e. minimal and reproducible), any comments are welcome.

Comment: @ProgramMasher that's way better, thank you. About your point on layouts, consider that no widget has a layout set, except for complex widgets that have "internal" layouts, like scroll areas (for scroll bars), QTabWidget (for the tab bar positioning) or QMainWindow (which is a special case, because its *actual* layout is the one that is responsible of adjusting geometries of menubar, statusbar, etc, and the "real user layout" is the one set for the *central widget*). In any other case, you must set the layout for it *not* by adding the layout from the widget box, but by right clicking on an ->

Comment: @ProgramMasher -> empty space of that container and selecting the preferred layout from the "Lay out" submenu. This might seem a bit unintuitive (and maybe there could have been better solutions) but it's done on purpose: layouts from the widget box are intended to be added to other layouts (*nesting*), not as main layouts for widgets.

Comment: That is exactly the issue I saw and that is exactly how I overcame it, but good to know why you have to add the widgets as you say.